# cocos2d-x Android device orientation:what i do wrong?

Tags: android, orientation, cocos2d-x

I tried change a device orientation in HelloWorld Android project. But, i have a small problem. I followed guide from off.site:

```
1. Add nativeInit(w, h); to cocos2dx/platform/android/java/src_common/org/cocos2dx/lib/Cocos2dxRenderer.java -> void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int w, int h).
2. Add this code to void Java_org_cocos2dx_lib_Cocos2dxRenderer_nativeInit(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz, jint w, jint h):


cocos2d::CCEGLView* view = cocos2d::CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getOpenGLView();
 if (!view) {
    ...
 } else {
    ...
    if (view->getFrameSize().width != w || view->getFrameSize().height != h) {
      view->setFrameSize(w, h);
      view->setDesignResolutionSize(w, h, kResolutionShowAll);
 }
}
```

So,my problem: in Portrait orientation i have a good view: [nice view](http://s9.postimage.org/4toqesien/shot_000003.png), but, in landscape orientation i have that:[bad view](http://s11.postimage.org/rjekhdj3n/shot_000002.png). What i do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing wrong with it, definitely you cannot using the same coordinates when you change your orientation. In you code, you should deal with them separately, for example:

```
if (orientationIsLandScape()) {
     background->setPosition();
} else {
     background->setPosition();
}
```

the `orientationIsLandScape()`should be some function written by yourself to detect the current orientation